# Problems using the ZTE Data Card AC2737

Tags: macos

I use a MacBook Air with the Mountain Lion(10.8.1). After upgrading from Lion, my Reliance Data card which is a ZTE AC2373 has stopped connecting. Is there a solution?

What data cards work with this operating system?
CN

Comment: All caps are frowned by our community. Being concise and accurate will allow us to help you easily, without the need for all caps.

Comment: What is the issue exactly, has Reliance produced any newer drivers? http://www.reliancenetconnect.co.in/downloads.html

Comment: The Data card is accessed by the system but when I try to connect, I get a message saying I need to check my settings or cntact the administrator. This was not happening when I was using the LION OSX 10.7 version.